# Error with apientry dllmain

Tags: c++, borland-c++, dllmain

I try to create *.dll file in Borland c++ 5.02, i have problem with this function

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

I try to compile my project but the compiler show the error. Any wrongs with this function or this compiler have different type style with another compiler?

Comment: Quite possibly. You really should get an up to date compiler, yours is 16 years old. There are several good free options.

Comment: What is the actual error being reported?

Comment: john : 16 it just my lucky number, i want to compare between borland and visual c++ 

remy : the compilation was failure, my DLL can't be create

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the examples for BC5.02, look in BC5\EXAMPLES\WINDOWS\DLLDEMO
The DLL entry point is defined as:

```
// Every DLL has an entry point LibMain || DllEntryPoint
// and an exit point WEP.
#if defined(__FLAT__)
BOOL WINAPI DllEntryPoint( HINSTANCE hinstDll,
                           DWORD fdwRreason,
                           LPVOID plvReserved)
#else /* not flat model  */
int FAR PASCAL LibMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,
                        WORD wDataSegment,
                        WORD wHeapSize,
                        LPSTR lpszCmdLine )
#endif /* __FLAT */
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a c style function ::

```
#define WINAPI __stdcall

extern "C" BOOL APIENTRY WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

if c++ style function ::

```
BOOL APIENTRY WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```